# Adding data to DataSet from different threads and showing them in DataGridView simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview, timer, dataset

I'm trying to add data to `DataSet` object from 3 different threads. All threads are `System.Threading.Timer` object threads because I'm using 3 separate timers (`System.Threading.Timer` type) in the program. After each `TimerCallback` delegate is invoked I'm acquiring data from some external PLCs (one timer for each PLC) and trying to put those data to `DataSet`. Acquiring data from PLCs works perfect because I'm able to display these data in some 
DataGridViews (one DataGridView for each PLC) There is also another`DataGridView` object (fourth) which should reflect all changes in `DataSet` immediately because it is bound to the DataSet. In the end these data I would like to put to database - but that's not a problem right now.

I need the data acquired from PLCs to put in the `DataSet` object. Also what I would like to see is watching all changes from `DataSet` in `DataGridView` right away after those changes take place.

I set the (fourth) `DataGridView` object properties as follows :

```
this.dgvxDataSet.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
this.dgvxDataSet.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables[0];
```

My code is as follows :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

DataSet _ds = new DataSet("dataSet1");
System.Threading.Timer timer1;
System.Threading.Timer timer2;
System.Threading.Timer timer3;


private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BuildDataSet();

    this.dgvxDataSet.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    this.dgvxDataSet.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables[0];
}

private void BuildDataSet()
{ 
    DataTable table1 = DataSet1.Tables.Add("table1");

    table1.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add("col4", typeof(Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add("col5", typeof(DateTime));
    table1.Columns.Add("col6", typeof(Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add("col7", typeof(Int32));
}    

private void btnReadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(PoolingStartPLC1), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    timer1.Change(0, (int)nudPollingTiming.Value);
    timer2 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(PoolingStartPLC2), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    timer2.Change(0, (int)nudPollingTiming.Value);
    timer3 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(PoolingStartPLC3), null, 0, Timeout.Infinite);
    timer3.Change(0, (int)nudPollingTiming.Value);            
}

public void PoolingStartPLC1(object state)
{
    /*
     Acquireing data from PLC1 which works fine
    */

    DataRow newRow;

    //I'm adding data to DataSet through MethodInvoker() because the DataSet was created in 
    //the main thread. 
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        newRow = DataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        newRow["col1"] = DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1;
        newRow["col2"] = variable11;
        newRow["col3"] = variable12;
        newRow["col4"] = variable13;
        newRow["col5"] = dateTimeVariable1;
    }));
}

public void PoolingStartPLC2(object state)
{
    /*
     Acquireing data from PLC2 which works fine
    */

    DataRow newRow;

    //I'm adding data to DataSet through MethodInvoker() because the DataSet was created in 
    //the main thread. 
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        newRow = DataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        newRow["col1"] = DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1;
        newRow["col2"] = variable21;
        newRow["col3"] = variable22;
        newRow["col4"] = variable23;
        newRow["col5"] = dateTimeVariable2;
    }));
}

public void PoolingStartPLC3(object state)
{
    /*
     Acquireing data from PLC3 which works fine
    */

    DataRow newRow;

    //I'm adding data to DataSet through MethodInvoker() because the DataSet was created in 
    //the main thread. 
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        newRow = DataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
        newRow["col1"] = DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1;
        newRow["col2"] = variable31;
        newRow["col3"] = variable32;
        newRow["col4"] = variable33;
        newRow["col5"] = dateTimeVariable3;
    }));
}


}
```

After a while the data should be in the `DataSet` object but the problem is they are not. During debugging I see empty `DataSet` and the `DataGridView` ofcourse doesn't display any rows ...

I don't know what am i doing wrong. Interestingly I don't receive any concurrency exceptions associated with adding data to the same `DataSet` object from 3 separate threads simultaneously. Maby I should use some locks or something (if any). If yes - I don't know how and where ... But the worst is that I don't know how put the data (which I have) to `DataSet`.

I'm using VS2010 Ultimate. The project is Windows forms project.

Thanks

Comment: This is a damn good question.  What framework version are you working with?

Comment: I'm using 4.0 framework. Actually the problem has been solved after Eric Sherrer's answer. I didn't add new rows to `DataSet`. I have forgotten :) honestly I'm expecting another problems with putting the data to date base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the row to the DataSet. One would think that .NewRow() adds the row but it doesn't - it just creates a new row that fits that DataSet table. Call DataSet1.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow). That should work.